# Isolating ports on a Cisco Catalyst 2960-X Switch

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-catalyst, power-over-ethernet, switchport

I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to networking, so excuse my ignorance for asking this.
I did try to post this on the Cisco support forums, but kept getting told it was spam haha, so I hope this is the appropriate place to post

Essentially we have 2 separate networks, one for our VoIP system, running off VLAN100 (As it was originally configured to host both voice and data) that contains all of our handsets, and the router for the dedicated VoIP internet connection. One of the switches in this network is a Cisco Catalyst 2960-X Series. We are getting a new CCTV camera that is PoE, and want to hook it up to our other network that is dedicated for data. It contains all the workstations, servers, and separate router for a dedicated data internet connection. But the switches on this network don't have PoE.
My question is, is there a way of separating 2 ports on the Cisco switch so that the PoE CCTV camera can connect to it for power, and then another connection going to the data network switch, so it essentially becomes part of the data network, without any interference from the VoIP network that is connected to all the other ports on the switch?

If someone would be able to let me know if this is doable or not, and if so, I'd love to know what exactly has to be setup for this to happen.
I'm new to networking, I've only ever programmed this Cisco switch once for some minor adjustments, but I'm not sure what even to search to get this setup, so I'm a bit stuck.

I thought that maybe having the separate VLAN's would work, but would prefer to have 2 ports working totally independent of the rest of the ports on the switch.

Thanks in advance for any help!! I hope this makes sense haha

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one switch interface, and you can only use the one switch interface for one interface in your camera. You could use an inline power injector if the switch interface you want to use for the camera doesn't have PoE.

You should really separate your standard data from any real-time data (VoIP, video, etc.) by using VLANs. VoIP, especially, can suffer if you mix the two on the same VLAN. It then becomes much easier to apply QoS to the traffic because you can simply base the marking on the VLAN. I would think you want a data VLAN, a VoIP VLAN, and a video VLAN. VoIP definitely needs priority queues, and video would benefit from separate priority queues, too.

Comment: So there is no way of separating a couple of ports on the switch?
We do have a separate VLAN for the VoIP system, but it is running on it's own separate network anyway..
If the Cisco switch I'm using for the VoIP is programmed with separate VLAN's, VLAN ID 100 for VoIP, and VLAN 1 for data, even though there is no computers connected to it for data, would this mean if I connect the CCTV camera to the Cisco switch, as well as connecting it to the other switch to connect to the existing data network, would that work fine? And cause no interference to the VoIP service?

Comment: If your camera only has one network interface, you can only use one switch interface to connect it to a switch. You can use an inline power injector to supply PoE for a non-PoE switch interface. Also, you really want a separate VLAN for video because you are likely to create problems for both your video and data if you mix them on the same VLAN.